# in Yii's criteria how to get count (*)

Tags: php, sql, yii

I'm trying to build a query that has a `group by` attribute,
im truing to get the `id` and the `count` 
it keeps telling me that the `count (*)` is **invalid** column name 
how could i get the `count` from the `group by` query ??

Comment: can u pls show the working code

Comment: do you use relations() method or you are trying something like
`Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('id, username, profile')
    ->from('tbl_user u')
    ->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
    ->queryRow();`

Comment: the answer is that we have to give the `'count (*)'` alias name like `'count (*) as count'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Work's with alias. Yii 1.1.11. Fails other

```
$criteria= new CDbCriteria();
$criteria=array(
            'group'=>'attribute',
            'select'=>'id,count(*) AS cc'
);
```

Comment: So how do I access it then? `$x = X::model()->findAll(...); $x[0]->cc` is not working..

Comment: It does if I add the variable into the model: `class X .. { public $cc;`. After that, the `$x[0]->cc` works.

Answer (score 5):

This not exactly an answer to your question, but could still be useful for you. If you use the result to only look up one count for one specific attribute, you don't need to fecth an entire array, but use Yii's `count` method:

```
$criteria= new CDbCriteria();
$criteria.compare('col_name', $desired_col_value);
$count = X::model()->count($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$criteria= new CDbCriteria();
$criteria=array(
            'group'=>'attribute',
            'select'=>'id,count(*) AS cc',
            'distinct'=>true,
);
```