# Yii add one more select to CDbCriteria

Tags: php, database, yii, orm

I'm relatively new to Yii.

I fell confident with raw SQL but still get a bit lost  when it comes to 
ORM. So this may be a dummy question.

I've retrieved all necessary records building such `CDbCriteria`:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
  'select' => 'sum(items) as items',
  // 'condition' => 't.items > 0 and order.storage = "'Product::STORAGE_LOCAL . '"',

  'condition' => 't.items > 0 and order.storage = "' .  Product::STORAGE_LOCAL . '"',
  'order' => 'sum(items) DESC',
  'with' => array(
    'product' => array(
       'select' => 'code, title, producer, local_rest',

        **// 'select' => 'code, title, producer, sum(local_rest) as   local_rest',**
       'group' => 'product.code',
    )
  ),

  'join' => 'inner join `order` `order` on `t`.`order_id` = `order`.`id`',
   // 'group' => '`product`.`code`, `product`.`title`',
   'group' => '`product`.`code`',
   'together' => true
));
```

I try to get sum of `local_rest` field doing `group by`. Unfortunately it does not return what it should be.

This is how I tried to build in it into `CDbCriteria`:

`// 'select' => 'code, title, producer, sum(local_rest) as   local_rest',`.
 - no luck.

I can get the it using separated query as:

```
$sum_local_rest = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
  SELECT  id,code, title, sum(local_rest) as sum_rest FROM product GROUP BY code
  ORDER BY `sum_rest`  DESC
");
```

One more caution - there are duplicate records in product table.
I.e. we have  the same product more than one time. But if I use `GROUP BY` it helps to delimiter this shortcoming. This is due to bad DB design and should be fixed in the future.

The problem is that I  need somehow to bind it with `CDbCriteria`, because it's used by `CDataProvider` and `CDataProvider` is used by `GridView`.

Any tips how to connect these two question in one `CDbCriteria`?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Looking at the current answers I feel I need summarize. The main problem is that I need to tell `CDbCriteria` to retrieve records (bound by HAS_Many connections) and to calculate SUM of all these records and to make `CDbCriteria` to do GROUP BY of these records.
No other way. I can't do it explicitly. Because I pass `CDbCriteria` to `CDataProvider` and it should run queries. This is how things work in Yii (as far as I understand).

Comment: have you tried select with array("column1",
"column2") ?  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail

Comment: Check also this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/12299137/3793566  and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16536633/3793566

Comment: the problem is I need get it from related table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also don't have to pass all elements to criteria. Try to split criteria into more code like this:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
 $criteria->select = 'sum(items) as items, ' . Product::STORAGE_LOCAL;
 $criteria->condition = 't.items > 0 and order.storage = ' .  Product::STORAGE_LOCAL;

//etc.
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess the resulting CDbCriteria will be the same and that above code is identical to  $criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(  'select'  => 'sum(items) as items, ' . Product::STORAGE_LOCAL, 'condition' => 't.items > 0 and order.storage = ' .  Product::STORAGE_LOCAL   ) );  . Perhaps this is jsut a question of taste.

Answer (score 3):

```html
//You can merge your criteria like here:

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();  //First criteria
$criteria_2 = new CDbCriteria();  //Second criteria

$criteria->mergeWith($criteria_2); //Merge criteria and criteria_2

SomeModel::model()->findAll($criteria); //Find by criteria
```

Comment: Good idea.  Although I can't see how splitting could help here besides making code more clear. Because I can't call findAll() manually.  CDataprovider does it instead of me.

Comment: @AlexShulzhenko You don't need to use findAll() because CActiveDataProvider will accept a criteria object as one of its parameters.  Since `$criteria_2` has been merged into `$criteria`, you only need pass `$criteria` to CActiveDataProvider to apply the conditions of both objects.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why something like this shouldn't work:

`` $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array(
    "SUM(t.items) as items",
    "SUM(product.local_rest) as product_local_rest"
);
$criteria->condition = "t.items > 0 and order.storage = "' .  Product::STORAGE_LOCAL . '"';
$criteria->join = 'inner join `order` `order` on `t`.`order_id` = `order`.`id`';
$criteria->with = "product";
$criteria->group = "product.code";
$criteria->together = true; ``

Since you're setting `together` to true, the columns of your relation should be available to your query, aliased by the relation's name (product). (Note: to access the result of SUM(product.local_rest) on the models returned by CActiveDataProvider, you'll need to set `$product_local_rest` as a public property on the class of the returned models.)

Alternatively, if you're more comfortable writing raw SQL, you could use CDbCommand to generate an array of results, and then use CArrayDataProvider instead of CActiveDataProvider. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider